# How add SockJS in my project anguylar2 rc4

Tags: angular, sockjs

I want to use websocket in my angular2 app with my server spring and I need to use SockJS.

Which command would I use to install it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try below,

```
  npm install sockjs-client
```

Read more on the configuration [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs-client)